# Downgrade Android target Api Level 23 to 22 in developer console

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-api-levels

I uploaded a new beta testing version with Android target api level 23. Before it was 22. I did not know, that with API Level 23 there are many changes regarding permissions. I realized that after uploading the new beta testing version with api level 23. So i build a new Version which was using api level 22 again to have more time to adapt my app to api level 23.

But every time now when i do upload a version with api level 22, i get an error in developer console "app could not be saved" with no more information about the error and i can not upload it. When I compile a new version with target API Level 23 it can be uploaded again. I think the problem is the downgrade to api Level 22.

Is it true, that once you published an API Level 23 version in closed beta testing, you can not downgrade back to target API Level 22?

Thanks for your help!

Smilingm

Comment: Did you build the new apk using a higher version code?

Comment: yes i did. I tried it multiple times...

Comment: Can you run your application with min level 22 in your phone? You should be able to change the min api level whenever you want (documentation doesn't say you can't: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html), have you any api 23 dependencies (ej. appcompat library)

Comment: It runs on all devieces on my phone. The problem is like Shmuel said, that its not possible to downgrade.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35301145/3514144

Answer (score 4):

message from Developer Console:

Android N final SDK available

You can now use the Developer Console to publish apps that target Android N devices (API level 24) to your production, alpha, and beta channels. **Keep in mind that once you publish an APK targeting API level 23 or higher, you won't be able to submit an update targeting API level 22 or lower on any channel.** 2016 Jun 15

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true.

> You can not downgrade back to target API Level 22.

Comment: although it is only in beta testing?

Comment: Yes, this is due to the new permission model. This error also applies if you try to install a new version (greater version code) of your app with target api 22 on your device with your api 23 beta installed: The installation gets rejected (error: new permission model) and you have to uninstall your beta before you can install you new version.