# Google Play app update - can't publish a new apk

Tags: android, google-play

I am getting the following error when trying to publish a new APK in Google Play:

**It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 2645 (target SDK 23) to version 2648 (target SDK 11).**

I previously published only on Beta channel an APK with a target SDK of 23 in the manifest, just for testing. 
I assume this is what causing the issue.

Does this mean I can't ever publish another APK with my regular manifest, which has a lower target SDK?

Did anyone encounter this and know of a way around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i want to show you something. hope you understand!

[image]

Comment: That SUCKS! Big time!!! They don't do it right and now my users can't use some of my app features because they think I'm asking for their CONTACTS permission.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same thing.  I'm stuck on Marshmallow because I upgraded my target SDK in Beta.

One would think that you can back out as far as you want on a beta or alpha channel as long as it has not been published to production.  That is the way it would work in the real world.

You only have a hind-site workaround.

The workaround is to not to develop for Marshmallow in Beta on your production app. Create a new application in Google Play and develop there until it is ready.  This will also let you update the production code if a bug fix comes up before your marshmallow release.