# Android APK publishing configuration error

Tags: android, google-play

[playstore Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W8Uc.png)

[image]

> It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below).
>
> This occurs in the change from version 101098 (target SDK 23) to version 70 (target SDK 0).

The thing is though, version 70 (target SDK 0) is the production version and version 101098 (target SDK 23) is the version that was in Beta and I'm now trying to upload a new version to Beta

[Versions in Beta Draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQbHt.png)

[image]

The reason the version numbers are so different is because it was a phonegap / cordova build which didn't pick up the correct version references and so generated one based on 1.1.9

Turns out that while [What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W8Uc.png)
 doesn't cover my error, a solution is pretty much the same.

- Don't deactivate / delete the previous beta version.
- Just upload and publish the new Beta version

no errors, but it doesn't like deactivating the old version afterwards

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300946/google-play-app-update-cant-publish-a-new-apk

Comment: The problem is not that I'm trying to use a lower SDK version, I'm targeting android-23.  I think this error is actually to do with the version in Beta I'm trying to replace.

Comment: Did you have any success with that?